# Merging a new string, containing number characters, with an existing number string

Tags: javascript

I have this string:

```js
let sx = ";1,2,3,4;5;10,11;"
```

The string has individual parts, separated by ";" which then are separated by "," thus the parts are as follows:

1,2,3,4 and 5 and 10,11

Numerically, the parts will always be in ascending order, but not necessarily consecutive.

The website's user then creates another "part", which might be "6,7,8,9", always consecutive, always different than any part of "sx", but random (it could be "28,29,30" or "15"). I have named this part "s1". The goal now is to join "sample" with "s1" and sort it, according to the first number of each part. Here is what I have tried:

```js
let sx = ";1,2,3,4;5;10,11;";
let s1 = "6,7,8,9";

//join "sx" with "s1", and split the new string by ";":
s1 = sx.concat(";" + s1 + ";");
s1 = s1.split(";").filter(Boolean);

//sort s1 by the first number of each part:
s1.sort(function(a, b) {
    var ax = a[0], bx = b[0];
    return parseInt(ax) - parseInt(bx);
});

console.log(s1);
```

Even though I use "parseInt", the result in the above example returns: "1,2,3,4,10,11,5,6,7,8,9".

What I need is: "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11" with the individual parts being:

"1,2,3,4" and "5" and "6,7,8,9" and "10,11", so then I can update the original string "sx" properly.

What am I doing wrong? By the way, I am not entirely sure if the end result is a string or an array(?), so please excuse the question's title!

Comment: In your sort function, `a` and `b` are still strings so index `[0]` is just the first character of each. Try `a.split(',')[0]`, etc

Comment: Wow! Thanks Phil, that was it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to get the first number of each part. `a[0]` and `b[0]` are not the first numbers of the parts, but the first characters of the strings, this is because `a` and `b` are strings, not arrays.

```js
let sx = ";1,2,3,4;5;10,11;";
let s1 = "6,7,8,9";

//join "sx" with "s1", and split the new string by ";":
s1 = sx.concat(";" + s1 + ";");
s1 = s1.split(";").filter(Boolean);

//sort s1 by the first number of each part:
s1.sort(function(a, b) {
  var ax = a.split(",")[0];
  var bx = b.split(",")[0];
  return parseInt(ax) - parseInt(bx);
});

//flatten the array into a single string with all the numbers separated by commas:
sx = s1.join(",");
console.log(sx);
```